# How to place 4 selectors in a row to fill exactly one col-sm-4 grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and making a simple form with `col-sm-4` grid. Now it looks as:

[image]

Also when I resize browser width to 507px, `C1` and `C2` elements slide down to the next line:

[image]

And by some reason my dropdown lists look as plain HTML without any styles, despite I add `class="selectpicker"` to them. I expect them to be like:

[image]

I want to get something like this:

[image]

This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j96vaokc/

What Bootstrap classes should I use?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple simple problems. First off, the selectpicker class is part of this Bootstrap jQuery plugin, [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/). You would have to download and include that script and stylesheet. Before that, you would also need to include the [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) script.

Here's a working fiddle to demonstrate what it'll look like with your code and the included scripts. Go to the 'External Resources' tab on the left to see which scripts/stylesheets I included and in which order:

https://jsfiddle.net/j96vaokc/5/

I added

```
.dropdown-toggle {
  width:60px !important
}
```

just to make the presentation neater on jsfiddle.

In regards to the wonky placement during window resize, that has a lot to do with your use of the bootstrap grid classes. In my fiddle you'll see that I removed alot of column classes since they weren't necessary. What I'm doing with the CSS is important because I have to override the default bootstrap-select styling for width in order to properly center. Also, in case you missed it I explicitly added a line break between the labels and select options.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this remark. Yes dropdowns look now nice, but again when I resize browser window they move to mess. Could you please recommend me what classes to use to get a responsive design?